# Visual Studio Sort usings in Wrong Order from SA1210

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, code-analysis, stylecop

This is a scenario I identified when we turned on Stylecop rule SA1210 in our project.
The below is the set of using in one file I tried this sorted by visual studio's Remove and Sort usings. 
I have configured to use System Directives first. Also, I have configured to automatically sort usings on file save.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using Bss.Cloud.Api.Caches.Redis;
using BSS.Angel.BusinessEntities.Cache;
using BSS.Angel.BusinessEntities.Lists;
using BSS.Angel.BusinessEntities.Repositories;
using BSS.Common.DataAccess.Claims;
```

But the above raised Stylecop SA1210.
When I use VS's intellisence's auto fix, I get

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using BSS.Angel.BusinessEntities.Cache;
using BSS.Angel.BusinessEntities.Lists;
using BSS.Angel.BusinessEntities.Repositories;
using Bss.Cloud.Api.Caches.Redis;
using BSS.Common.DataAccess.Claims;
```

The reason being `Cloud` > `Angel`.

This makes it difficult for me as when I save, It gets sorted back to the old VS' Sort Using way.
Their reason being `BSS` > `Bss` according to Visual studio.

Now I cannot save the SA passing way(I have automatic sort enabled). VS does not support style cop way.
We cannot update the `BSS` to `Bss` as this is a huge change in a different library project for us.

Is there something I can do for Stylecop to be compatible with Visual Studio and not disable Automatic Sort using on save.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the StyleCop rule -- I would have expected it to sort the same as VS. Why not ask them about it? [This is their issue tracker](https://github.com/StyleCop/StyleCop/issues)

Comment: I intend to do that if i cannot find anything here.

Comment: Also, if you've got VS configured to sort usings on save, why do you have SA1210 enabled at all? Surely there's no point - everything gets fixed when you save.

Comment: It is not just me working on the project. I have enabled Sort on save so that I do not need to specifically do that. Many people does not even know there is an option to sort usings automatically (`Ctrl+R+G`) let alone on save.

Comment: One does case sensitive sorting, other does case insensitive sorting. I agree with VS here. Terrible mistake from stylecop. Good catch! Did you try with latest stylecop?

Comment: @nawfal adipoli